# Laravel-8 Related data in a collection is lost

Tags: laravel-8

I am trying to get more familiar with laravel/livewire. I find myself struggling with collections with related data. In my component i get data from the database and store it in a variable, with related data. When i do a dd after the retrieval, i see a complete collection with the related data. In my bladefile i have a foreach loop to display all the lists and for each list i have a foreachloop to display all todos.

But when i want to edit a list, i want to show one of the lists in a modal with a form. I call a function 'edit_todo' and i want to extract the data from my collection to fill in a blade form.

But when i look at the same variable as before ($this->todolists) in that function, the related data is missing.

This is a part of the code.

```
class Dashboard extends Component
{
    public $todolists, $list_id, $todolist;

    public function render()
    {
        $this->todolists = TodoList::with('todos')->get();

        //dd($this->todolists); //<-- relationsproperty shows all todos from each list

        return view('livewire.dashboard');
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public function edit_todo($list_id)
    {
        dd($this->todolists);  //<-- relationsproperty is empty 

        $this->todolist = $this->todolists->where('id',$list_id)->with('todos')->first()->toArray();
    }
```

Any suggestions? What am i doing wrong?
Maybe i just have to get the data again from the database, but i'd like to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Did you try ? $this->todolist = $this->todolists->where('id',$list_id)->first()

Comment: That line isn't the problem. The dd above it results in the collection, but without the related data.
So in the function Render() the variable $this->todolists contains all my todolists including the related Todo's,  but later in the function edit_todo() the variable $this->todolists only contain the todolists but not the related Todo's.

Answer (score 0):

Move the population of your `$todoLists`  to the mount method:

```
public function mount()
{
    $this->todolists = TodoList::with('todos')->get();
}
```

Have a look at https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks and you'll notice that the render method is only requested at the very end. If you need your `$todoLists` populated as you wish, move it up in the list of lifecycle hooks.

Edit & extra: `mount()` in LiveWire is equal to `__construct()` in any other class as we are used to. Whatever you would like to 'construct', write it in the mount method.

Comment: Thnx Dimitri, i tried that, but the result is the same....

Comment: I haven't test it myself @ErwinVanMaasakkers You may have found a bug. The other day I went through the LiveWire source code, it's written in a higher level PHP language that I can't comprehend. As such, few people can debug the code.